# Why is javaFX is too slow with arabic on runtime?

Tags: javafx

When I run this code for example, it works normal:

```
public class AllControlsReff extends Application{

    @Override     
    public void start(Stage Scr) throws Exception {
        Scr.show();
        Scr.setTitle("All Controls Reference");


        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        VBox vb = new VBox(10);

        TitledPane Tp;
        TilePane numPad;

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            Tp = new TitledPane();
            numPad = new TilePane();
            Tp.setText("English Title: " + i);
            for(int j=0;j<18;j++){
                numPad.setHgap(10);
                numPad.setVgap(10);
                numPad.setPrefColumns(9);
                numPad.setStyle("-fx-font-size:20;");
                Button btn = new Button("button " + j);
                btn.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("-"));
                numPad.getChildren().add(btn);
            }
            Tp.setContent(numPad);
            vb.getChildren().add(Tp);
        }
        sp.setContent(vb);
        Scene pg = new Scene(sp,1280,720);
        Scr.setScene(pg);
    }
}
```

but when I use the same example with Arabic language, it works very slowly at runtime, hard to click on buttons or collapse the TitledPanes:

```
Tp.setText("عنوان بالعربية: " + i);     
Button btn = new Button("العربية " + j);
```

I didn't test on Windows to see the different, currently I use Ubuntu, and run my Java application from terminal.

Comment: If you're on Linux - it's a bug, fixed in JavaFX 11 IIRC https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8129582

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar slowdown on Windows 10 running Java 10 using both methods. I moved the `Src.show()` to the end of the start method and it seems to have fixed the initial slowdown.

I saw no discernible time delay on button presses in either case.

Comment: I test your suggestion by moving the  Src.show() to the end, but same problem, still supper slow to click on buttons or collapse the TitledPanes.

Comment: It may be environmental then. I saw no slowness on button clicks or title pane collapses in my environment. I am using Java 10 on 64 bit Windows 10 Pro with 8gb of ram. Not sure if that helps any.

Comment: Yes maybe, I use also Java 10, but in Ubuntu 64bit with 8gb of ram.I will try to run the code on windows later. 

by the way, wxPython works very fast in the same  environment.